# Form not saved in database by POST request in django view

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

My form was working fine but suddenly it stops working and I'm stuck here, help me please!
When I prints form.errors in case of form not valid then it prints

> user
>
> is a required field.

**models.py**

```
class TarWithDocker(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='deployments')
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', unique=True, name='slug')
archive = models.FileField(upload_to='archives', name='archive')
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created_at']
```

**views.py**

```
class AwdDeployment(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
template_name = 'deployments/awdDeployment.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'deployments/awdDeployment.html', {})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AwdDeploymentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            deployment = TarWithDocker()
            deployment.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            deployment.user = self.request.user
            deployment.archive = form.cleaned_data['archive']
            deployment.save()
            return HttpResponse("Submitted")
        else:
            print("not saved")

    else:
        print("something happnes wrong")
        form = AwdDeploymentForm()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:deployments:awd'))
```

Comment: do a print(self.request.user) and check if user is getting printed in the terminal or not

Comment: it prints username in terminal!

Comment: did you get it working???

Comment: yup, thanks! it works now by using bear's answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have user in request, but may be not in post data
May be it help you:

```
post_data = request.POST.copy()
post_data.update({'user': request.user.pk})
form = AwdDeploymentForm(post_data, request.FILES)
```

Comment: I'm using LoginRequiredMixin which provides user object within request !

Comment: it's works in your way, but is there any reason that user is not available in request?

Comment: the mixin add user to the request but not in post data